# jsViews - how do I set selected option from data

Tags: jsrender, jsviews

I have a select which is bound to some values from the server using jsViews. I have successfully managed to show the options but I want be able to track and set the select option to the value from my JavaScript object.  This is my code:

```
<select id="albumChoice" data-link="selectedAlbum">
    <option value="-">Please select</option>
    {^{for albums}}
    <option data-link="{value{:id} text{:name}} selected{:selectedAlbum}}"></option>
    {{/for}}
</select>
```

The complete example code is in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4ZevT/

As you can see I have tried to use selected{:selectedAlbum} but that doesn't do anything. What must I do so that the option is automatically set when the page loads to the value from the server.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an example here:

http://www.jsviews.com/#jsvplaying.
(See at the end of the section: ***Sample:*** data-linking to `<select>`... and much more...)

I have updated your fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/4ZevT/2/

You syntax for data-link on the `<option...`  has some errors. I updated it to:

`<option data-link="value{:id} {:name} selected{:id == ~root.selectedAlbum}"></option>`

The selected binding expects a Boolean, not a number...

I had to set `selected{:id == ~root.selectedAlbum}` rather than `selected{:id === ~root.selectedAlbum}` because you are using number values for you ids. If you change them to strings, you can switch to `===`.

Comment: Thanks Boris. If I have multiple select controls on my page is there a better way to track the selected values? For example if I had the follwing selects: FirstAlbumChoice, SecondAlbumChoice. If I had this I would need to define two variables at the root. Is there a way to make it dynamic so I can add as many selected variables as I want?

Comment: It's OK I think I will digest this example (http://www.jsviews.com/#samples/tagcontrols/multiselect) and try to use the concepts shown there. Thanks.