# JsViews: What is the syntax for data-linking to <select> ... <option> ...?

Tags: drop-down-menu, jsviews

```js
var app = {
    selections: {
        things: [
            { Name: "name1", Value: "thingValue1" },
            { Name: "name2", Value: "thingValue2" },
            { Name: "name3", Value: "thingValue3" }
        ],
        places: [
            { Name: "place1", Value: "placeValue1" },
            { Name: "place2", Value: "placeValue2" },
            { Name: "place3", Value: "placeValue3" }
        ]
    },
    formData: {
        selectedThing: "thingValue1",
        selectedPlace: "placeValue1"
    }
};

var template = $.templates("#theTmpl");

template.link("#content", app);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.jsviews.com/download/jsviews.js"></script>


<div id="content"></div>

<script id="theTmpl" type="text/x-jsrender">
    <select id="thingChoice" data-link="formData.selectedThing">
        <option value="-">Please select</option>
        {^{for selections.things}}
        <option data-link="{value{:Value} text{:Name}} selected{:formData.selectedThing}}"></option>
        {{/for}}
    </select>
    <select id="placeChoice" data-link="formData.selectedPlace">
        <option value="-">Please select</option>
        {^{for selections.places}}
        <option data-link="{value{:Value} text{:Name}} selected{:formData.selectedPlace}}"></option>
        {{/for}}
    </select>
</script>
```

In this jsfiddle, I am trying to separate my several item lists from the data structure I'll be POSTing to the server:
http://jsfiddle.net/hdra2e2d/1/

Here is the problem:  only the first item has text in the selection dropdown!  Everything looks to be hooked up correctly, though I haven't found any Super-Simple or Concise examples of data-binding to a SELECT html form element so maybe I missed something when bending a nearest-possible match into this attempt?

background details:  The intent is to fetch available items for several dropdown lists as JSON and stuff them into discrete dictionary-arrays within the "app.selections" member, data-link to them and have their user-selected values stored in the "app.formData" object which I'll be POSTing as JSON to the server.

Comment: I am curious where you found that syntax for the <option> data-link expression? BTW I updated your title so others can find this question/answer. See my answer below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax for

```
<option data-link="{value{:Value} text{:Name}} selected{:formData.selectedThing}}"></option>
```

is very strange. Where did that come from? You seem to have taken the same erroneous syntax that was in this question: [jsViews - how do I set selected option from data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18090383/jsviews-how-do-i-set-selected-option-from-data).

The correct syntax for the option is

```
<option data-link="value{:Value} {:Name} selected{:~selected === Value}"></option>
```

(as shown in the answer to that question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18154317/1054484.)

See also the last sample here: http://www.jsviews.com/#jsvplaying

Here is a corrected version of your jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/BorisMoore/8dwdkp2d/.

Note that this syntax will allow you to dynamically update the displayed `Name` and `Value` values; Try changing the textbox value in my jsfiddle version.

An alternative syntax if you don't need to dynamically update the `Name` and `Value` values is:

```
<option value="{{:Value}}" selected="{{:~selected === Value}}">{{:Name}}</option>
```

For understanding the syntax for the data-link expressions, see http://www.jsviews.com/#linked-elem-syntax

Comment: Thanks for the correction!  I must have carried over some bad syntax from a question that was the closest to what I needed.  Strangely enough, changing the ":" to a "^" in the per-option data-link setting appears to work, here is an updated jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/hdra2e2d/6/

Comment: Well that syntax is still incorrect... See http://www.jsviews.com/#linked-elem-syntax for information on how the data-link syntax works...

Comment: Got it, thanks again. - Reading through this I am puzzled by the actual meaning of ":", "~" and "^", are they explicitly defined somewhere for each context in which they might be used?

Comment: I'm working on new doc topics on this. But for "^" see http://www.jsviews.com/#linked-tag-syntax. For "~" see http://www.jsviews.com/#helpers. For ":" see the link I gave you,  http://www.jsviews.com/#linked-elem-syntax - the paragraph: "The corresponding full syntax is a data-linked {{: ...}} tag" ... talking about the full syntax - related to http://www.jsviews.com/#assigntag.